# Is there an equivalent to a C++ lock_guard in threading with Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, with-statement

Beginning to work with the [Python threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#)  after coming from C++.

There exists a class in C++ called a [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), in which the object takes control of a provided lock, and then destructs the lock_guard object & releases the lock upon exit of the scope in which the lock_guard was created.

After doing some research, it appears that using a [`with`  statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) with a `Lock` object to create a runtime context under the control of a context manager may be the closest equivalent. So, something like this...

```py
myLock = threading.Lock()

with myLock:
    # My critical region here ...
```

My understanding is that the  `with` statement will release the lock upon exit, in similar fashion to a C++ `lock_guard.`

Is this a correct mapping to make?  If not, what is a better equivalent to a `lock_guard` in Python's threading library? And if so, is there nuance I am missing here?

Comment: That is my interpretation as well.

Comment: When leaving the "with"-block, the lock is released.

Comment: This is covered in Python's documentation: [Using locks, conditions, and semaphores in the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement): "*All of the objects provided by this module that have `acquire()` and `release()` methods can be used as context managers for a `with` statement. The `acquire()` method will be called when the block is entered, and `release()` will be called when the block is exited.*"